# Exit Code 0 instead of printing?

Tags: java, printing

I have the following java code written and when I run it it says: "Process finished with exit code 0" instead of printing totalNumCars(). Why is this, and how do I fix it?

```
public class ParkingGarage extends Module5{

    public int numAutomobiles;
    public int numLargeAutomobiles;
    public static int numGarages;

    public ParkingGarage(int automobiles, int largeAutomobiles){
        numAutomobiles = automobiles;
        numLargeAutomobiles = largeAutomobiles;
        numGarages++;
    }

    public void addCars(int newAutomobiles, int newLargeAutomobiles){
        numAutomobiles += newAutomobiles;
        numLargeAutomobiles += newLargeAutomobiles;
    }

    public int totalNumCars(){
        int totalCars = numLargeAutomobiles + numAutomobiles;
        return totalCars;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ParkingGarage garage1 = new ParkingGarage(5,5);
        garage1.addCars(5, 5);
        System.out.println("Number of Cars: " + garage1.totalNumCars());
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's printing _absolutely_ nothing else, then you may not be calling the right main method (e.g. do you have multiple?). Otherwise that's the line your IDE puts out after the program has run, an exit code of 0 means the program successfully reached the end of the main method (and some other conditions you learn later on)

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/Xj9HNs) Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: which in turn implies the printout is likely going *somewhere* - but that could well depend on your IDE (assuming you're using an IDE).

Comment: Your code is working fine...